# Expected value: Is $E|X| = |E(X)|$?

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

Is the expectation of absolute value equal to the absolute value of the expectation? $E|X| = |E(X)|$ seems intuitively true to me, but I couldn't find it online. I wanted to check whether this is true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not true in general. 
E.g., let $X$ be the random variable whose value is $-1$ or $+1$, both with probability $1/2$. Then $|X|$ is $+1$ with probability $1$, so $|E(X)|= |0| = 0$ and $E(|X|)=1$.

The only thing you can claim is $|E(X)|\leq E(|X|)$, and it is trivial.

Comment: If the reader does not find the latter it trivial, it is a result of the triangular inequality.

Comment: @Jonas Not needed, simply use $-|X|\leqslant X\leqslant|X|$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and let $X$ be a random variable. Then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[X] := \int_{\Omega} X\, d\mathbb P
\end{align*}
This is the Lebsegue integral of $X$ over the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal F, \mathbb P)$. Now the answer should be obvious. In general
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Omega} |X|\, d\mathbb P \neq \left|\int_{\Omega} X\, d\mathbb P\right|
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

It is not true in general.

Counter example: Let $X$ take value $+1$ with probability $0.5$ and $-1$ with probability $0.5$.

Then $|X|=1$ so that $\mathbb E|X|=1$.

But $|\mathbb EX|=|0|=0$.